# NSObject loading UIView with nib but fileowner is UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinib

I have a custom object which handles some operations with views. Basically it initializes a UIView with a nib file. But I want my viewcontroller to be responsible to handle IBActions. So I setted my viewcontroller to be the file owner and connected IBActions.

In my custom object I load nib file like this:

```
self.nibView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nibName" owner:delegate options:optionsDict] lastObject];
```

I setted delegate which is my UIViewController(kind of strange) to be the owner. So I was expecting my viewcontroller to handle IBActions but it did not. My custom object tried to respons the action and of course application crashed because of not responding to selector. How can I achieve that ?

Edit:

View Controller
[image: View Controller]

Custom Object
[image: Custom Object]

Nib File
[image: Nib File]

Comment: what is nibView here?? I mean is it an array??

Comment: no, it is a custom view.

Comment: First thing, loadNibNamed method return an array. So you cannot return in view

Comment: I am assigning to lastObject of the array

Comment: Ohk i did not see thats right. So now you wanted to write action method programmatically?

Comment: I can write actions programmatically. What I want is connecting the  actions in the nib file.

Comment: Your problem is not clear when your say you can write action method programmatically then what is the need of connection??

Comment: Because it will ease my job. Actually, I use this custom object in many places. So I don't want to connect actions programmatically, code will be very large if I do it. If I can achieve to connect them with nib file, it will really make things easier for me.

Comment: Oh so you just need to connect with bindings right? If yes then it is very easy to do, Where you got stucked??

Comment: I edited my question. Thing is, I connected it in nib file and my I want my view controller to be owner and responder but, my custom object which owns the view objects became responder

Answer (score 0):

The delegate is a protocol, the owner should be an object.

If your view controller conforms to the delegate protocol, you should set `owner:self`
and ensure that the delegate property of the view is set to be your view controller. This can be done in IB using the IBOutlet, or in code by something like: `self.nibView.delegate = self`

Comment: I know delegate is a protocol, that's why I wrote kind of strange there but I could not understand your solution